# Is it possible for an IF statement to be in the for loop's third expression (C)?

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop

While learning from K&R, I tried to modify the while loop in exercise 1.5.3 in to a for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int c, nl;

  for (nl = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; if (c == '\n'){++nl}){}
  printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

SIDE NOTE: I apologize if this code looks abominable. For now, I am just trying to write valid C code, and when I feel that I have adapted to the language's general concepts, I will start writing code for "humans."

When I try to build and run the code, this message appears,

```
error: expected expression before 'if'
```

I tried to search this error, but I could only find answers that either referred to other languages or ternary operations, which I would like to avoid if possible. Thanks in advance for any insight into resolving this issue, if it even is one.

Comment: "I am just trying to write valid C code" Well, you lost already with the second line. The signature of `main` is wrong.

Comment: @Olaf I have not learned signatures yet, but after implementing Barmar's solution below, the code built and ran like it was intended to. Looking up signatures right now, it looks like they are related to function returns; is there a "beneficial" bug in my compiler?

Comment: I wrote about the signature, i.e. _declaration_ of `main`. Not sure which kind of signatures you talk about. You should have learned that in the first place: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1. An environment might enforce one of them, e.g POSIX the latter variant (Windows similar, IIRC). Anything else is invalid. Note that your version is pre-standard and shall generate a warning by the compiler since C99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` is a statement, the header of a `for` loop can only contain expressions, not statements.

You can use a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) there, it's the way to perform a conditional in an expression.

```
for (nl = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; (c == '\n') ? ++nl : 0) {}
```

Comment: Thank you. All of the answers here are great, but I think yours both explains and solves this question the best.

Answer (score 3):

No, but if you really want to squeeze it in the loop (although I would not recommend it), you could do

```
nl += (c == '\n')? 1: 0
```

Or, as **@LogicG8** suggested, just

```
nl += (c == '\n')
```

although it is a bit less clear and may violate some coding guidelines.

Comment: Why not just for (nl = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; nl += (c == 'n')) {} and leave out the condition altogether.

Comment: @LogicG8 Sure, it would work, but I am not sure if it is a good practice. Anyway, I extended the post, hopefully you do not mind.

Answer (score 2):

No, not possible. The third clause has to be an expression and `if` statements are statements, not expressions.

Answer (score -1):

In short: This is not possible, you could use some inline-ifs somehow, though.

**But**, even in case it would work, you shouldn't do it because....

- ...the simpler the for-loop, the better the optimization. Don't confuse the compiler.
- ...you might also confuse other developers if they have to read and unerstand that code.

Keep it simple whenever possible.